# Why am I getting wrong 0 index of value?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am trying to learn how to add dynamically data into a list but I am facing a problem.
Why am I getting wrong value index of 0. when ever I trying to add a value position of index.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyList{
    String[] mList = null;
    int pointer;

    public MyList(){
        mList = new String[pointer];
    }

    public void add(String aStringValue){
        System.out.println("add: "+pointer+ " " +aStringValue+ " "+mList.length);
        if (pointer < mList.length-1) {
            System.out.println(pointer+ " " +aStringValue);
            mList[pointer] = aStringValue;
            pointer++;      
        }else{
            System.out.println("New List:");
            String[] lStringList = new String[mList.length + 20];
            System.arraycopy(mList, 0, lStringList, 0, mList.length);
            mList = lStringList;
            System.out.println("New List: "+mList.length);
        }
    }

    public int size(){
        int size = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i<mList.length;i++) {
            if (mList[i] == null) {
                return size;
            }else{
                size++;
            }
        }
        return size;
    }

    public String get(int index){
        return mList[index];
    }
}

public class ListSize{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyList lList = new MyList();
        lList.add("Amit");
        lList.add("Deepak");
        lList.add("Vishal");
        lList.add("hello");
        lList.add("abc");
        lList.add("rahul");
        lList.add("ajit");
        lList.add("durgesh");
        lList.add("a");
        lList.add("b");
        lList.add("c");
        lList.add("d");
        lList.add("e");
        System.out.println("MyList is: "+lList.size());
        for (int i = 0; i<lList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(lList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the Output of Amit, Deepak but the Actual output is Deepak, vishal

Comment: `lList.get(i-1)`

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new array, you don't add anything to it. I suggest you always check the size is ok, and afterwards, always add the element. If you want to see this clearly, I suggest stepping through the code in your debugger.

```
public void add(String aStringValue) {
    // ensure capacity.
    if (pointer == mList.length)
        mList = Arrays.copyOf(mList, mList.length + 20);

    mList[pointer++] = aStringValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `add` method, if the array hasn’t got room for the string you want to add, you are creating a new and bigger array, but not adding the string to the new array.

I believe that the code in the `if` part of your `if` statement should go after the `if` statement instead.